# Save data on SDCard in a secure way in Android

Tags: android, sd-card

I want to save some files on SDCard which will be downloaded from net. The user should not be able to have direct access to it. I mean the file should be secure and it should not be transferred to other device and if its transferred then it should not be in readable format. Is there a particular directory on SDCard where these files can be saved and be secure too? Also this files should be automatically deleted on uninstall of the app. I guess there is a direct way of that in Android 2.2 but not below that. So, if someone has any idea of doing that then please let me know.

Comment: What you are trying to do is implement DRM. There are only two types of DRM -- the ones that have been broken and the ones that nobody has bothered trying to break yet.

Comment: Hi I am facing same probled...

Did u get answer of this if yes please share it

Thanks in advance

Comment: @CommonsWare can you post a simple example of reading a DRM protected file in Android? Current examples available on internet are confusing!

Answer (score 2):

Encryption. If you're concerned about the user reading a file that's the closest answer you'll find -- but you need a secure way to store the decryption key also, which is not really attainable.

Realistically, anything that must not be viewed by the device owner must not be on the device.

Comment: The device owner can view only through the app and not by any other means. For eg, say books are purchased by users thru the app and then app saves the book in users device. For reading the book user can start the app and then read it. But the user should not be able to share that with someone else.

Comment: @android_dev: your best bet here then will be to have the data encrypted using a key based on the user's password. You could make the key be a combination of the user's password and something unique to the device (that you store within the application's shared prefs, for example). This is not iron clad security, but that's not attainable with anything you've stored on the device.

Comment: I think if this were possible it would be used currently by most companies to prevent piracy.  I'm wondering how such a system can exist; you can download files from a to b, but can't copy them from b to c?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in the physical possession of a dedicated user there is no practical way to make them impossible to copy. You can make them DIFFICULT to copy, but not impossible.

If you use encryption as @mah pointed out, and then don't store the key on the device: fetch the key from a server, retain it in memory and never write out the decrypted file or the key to disk you might be ok in deterring the casual pirate. The dedicated souls will figure it out.